# Parse and compare a list and a dictionary and output values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am in a bit of a mess. I need to compare a list of users with a list of dictionaries. Both are given by previous functions, and after the compare, I need to get a list of dictionaries where the users match or if they do not match - a list with a string 'Not found in list' for each user and the details for the others.
Here is the code that I am working on:

```
users = [[u'ken'], [u'ted']]

user_id = [
{u'UserName': u'ted', u'LastSeen': u'x'},
{u'UserName': u'ken', u'LastSeen': u'x'}
]

user_list = []
for user in users:
    user_list.append(user[0])
a = user_list
user_details = []
for element in user_id:
    for element2 in a:
        if element['UserName'] == element2:
            user_details.append(element)
        else:
            user_details = [element2 + ' ' + 'not found in list']
            break
    print user_details
Output:
[u'ken not found in list']
[u'ted not found in list']
```

The desired output - in case the user (as above match) would be:

```
user_details = [{u'UserName': u'ted', u'LastSeen': u'x'}, {u'UserName': u'ken', u'LastSeen': u'x'}]
```

Or in case `users = [[u'barby'], [u'ted']]`

The desired output would be:

```
user_details = ['not found in list', {u'UserName': u'ted', u'LastSeen': u'x'}]
```

If I comment the 'else' and below it - I get the desired list - but it does not work for me, as I may have users not listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of things wrong. First you are checking for every position of user_id if each user is equal to it so you are going to get to the else multiple times for each case depending on the number of users you have.
Other problem is you have to append in the else instead of replacing the string or you will lose what was saved in that variable.
Here is an example working code:
The for, else statement does the else whenever it doesn't break inside, in other words, whenever you don't find an user in the list you append that string.

```
users = [[u'ken'], [u'ted']]

user_id = [
{u'UserName': u'ted', u'LastSeen': u'x'},
{u'UserName': u'ken', u'LastSeen': u'x'}
]

user_list = []
for user in users:
    user_list.append(user[0])
a = user_list
user_details = []
for element2 in a:
    for element in user_id:
        if element['UserName'] == element2:
            user_details.append(element)
            break
    else:
        user_details.append([element2 + ' ' + 'not found in list'])

print(user_details)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - the last version is what I was looking for. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create a mapping of the `UserName` to the `dict` in the `user_id` list:

```
users = [[u'ken'], [u'ted']]

user_id = [
    {u'UserName': u'ted', u'LastSeen': u'x'},
    {u'UserName': u'ken', u'LastSeen': u'x'}
]

seen_map = {u['UserName']: u for u in user_id}

user_details = []
for u in users:
    try:
        user_details.append(seen_map[u[0]])
    except KeyError:
        user_details.append('{0} not found in list'.format(u[0]))

print user_details

# for users = [[u'ken'], [u'ted']]
# [{u'UserName': u'ken', u'LastSeen': u'x'}, {u'UserName': u'ted', u'LastSeen': u'x'}]
# for users = [[u'barby'], [u'ted']]
# ['barby not found in list', {u'UserName': u'ted', u'LastSeen': u'x'}]
```

This way you only have to loop over the `user_id` list once to create the mapping, not once for each element in `users`.